# How do I enable the radio button after I disable it?

Tags: vba, radio-button

I put my code like this, so when I select that radio button it will disable the same button in other form. But I realized if I select another radiobutton it will not enable, which means my code will only help me disable the radiobutton but not help me enable it back. But I have no idea how to.
Here's my code

```
If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Form1.TextBox1.Text = "Literary Studies and Creative Writing 10"
        Form12.RadioButton1.Enabled = False
        Form20.RadioButton1.Enabled = False
    End If
```

Comment: why are you disabling the other radio buttons. Do you simply want to instead have a setup where only one radio button is selected at a time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you're asking is somewhat ambiguous, but just for the sake of helping I want to throw in some ideas.

You could make a "reset state" function inside your forms and that function can enable back all the radios or empty textbox, etc.

So whenever you want to enable back the controllers in a different form you can re enable them calling that function maybe on some event related to the form.

For example :

```
Function EnableRadios()    
  RadioButton1.Enabled = True
  RadioButton2.Enabled = True
End Function
```

Also if you make your forms work as a template your function could work in any form, the more standard your form is the better approach you will have on the task.

Comment: this question is tagged `vba`

Comment: You're right @ArcherBird updating the function definition so it will proper fit the VBA sintax.